# Fast interleave operation in C?

Tags: c, arrays, performance, memcpy

I need to combine two arrays into a third in chunks of four.
Specifically, for input arrays

```
    A0, A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6, A7 ...
    B0, B1, B2, B3, B4, B5, B6, B7 ...
```

the output should be

```
    A0 A1 A2 A3   B0 B1 B2 B3   A4 A5 A6 A7   B4 B5 B6 B7, ...,
```

In a sense, this is the reverse of the de-interleave question asked in [Fastest de-interleave operation in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14567786/fastest-de-interleave-operation-in-c)

For some extra fun, the two buffers contain elements that are respectively eight and sixteen bits wide. I have written some code to do this but profiling indicates that it is spending a lot of time, so I am looking for ways to speed it up.
As my target CPU (LEON) does not provide them, SIMD intrinsics are not an option. My CPU has a word length of 16 bits.

I have tried different ways of doing the loop and this is the fastest version I have so far:

```
#include <stdint.h>

#define BUFSZ 1024

register int i;
int8_t  A[BUFSZ]; // 1st buffer
int16_t B[BUFSZ]; // 2nd buffer
int16_t interleaved[2*BUFSZ]; // the two buffers combined

int8_t  *pA;
int16_t *pB, *pinterleaved;

        pinterleaved=interleaved;
        for(i=BUFSZ/4, pA=A, pB=B; i-->0; pinterleaved+=8, pA+=4, pB+=4){
                pinterleaved[0]=pA[0]; pinterleaved[1]=pA[1]; pinterleaved[2]=pA[2]; pinterleaved[3]=pA[3];
                pinterleaved[4]=pB[0]; pinterleaved[5]=pB[1]; pinterleaved[6]=pB[2]; pinterleaved[7]=pB[3];
        }
```

Any ideas for a faster implementation?

Comment: Looks pretty tight to me. Have you tried writing 32 bits at a time instead of 16? - I mean, have `interleaved` be an array of `int32_t`. I seem to recall that certain CPU models are slower with 16-bit memory writes - I don't have experience with yours specifically.

Comment: Post the assembly that the compiler generates for this code.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have a 16 bit CPU, so doing it with 32 bits should be slower, although I have not tested it.

Comment: Is the decrementing `i` part of a performance improvement?

Comment: It's a bit off topic but instead of optimizing this task, did you check that the task is really necessary ? Can't you just use A and B directly in the following of your program instead of copying everything in `interleaved` ? I don't see the added value of this copy, espacilly since both arrays seem to contain heterogeneous data. When optimizing some code, you have to take the big picture and not necessarily focus on just one function.

Comment: @Guillaume Petitjean: unfortunately the copying is necessary as the combined data are meant to be send via DMA to a hardware accelerator

Comment: @4386427: Sort of, although counting upwards is not much different in terms of speed.

Comment: As @EOF said, it would be good to look at the assembly to find out if something can be optimized.

Comment: It's unlikely you can optimize this C code given the shortcomings of the CPU, unless the assembly shows something particularly egregious.

Comment: @PSkocik: Why do you believe the OP’s LEON processor has SIMD instructions?

Answer (score 3):

Optimizing performance is often a very system specific task. So my observation may not be valid on your system.

Anyway, FWIW, on my system I see a performance improvement by replacing the 4 last assigns (those using `pB`) with a `memcpy`.

I replaced:

```
pinterleaved[4]=pB[0]; pinterleaved[5]=pB[1]; pinterleaved[6]=pB[2]; pinterleaved[7]=pB[3];
```

with

```
memcpy(pinterleaved + 4, pB, 4 * sizeof *pB);
```

and got a > 25% performance improvement.

Comment: This may be a bit crazy, but if OP benefits from `memcpy`, I would also try temp buffer for 8 `uint8_t`, fill appropriate position with the short values and `memcpy` it to the destination:
`int8_t  T[8]; 
T[1] = pA[0]; T[3] = pA[1]; T[5] = pA[2]; T[7] = pA[3]; 
memcpy(pinterleaved, T, 8);`