# kCVReturnPixelBufferNotOpenGLCompatible error

Tags: iphone, ios

I am  getting frames of video and creating a PixelBuffer from two planar arrays extracted from video frame using the function CVPixelBufferCreateWithPlanarBytes() and I have checked the generated pixelbuffer from CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer =CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) and created pixelbuffer are same , but when i am creating a texture using CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage() it returns error -6683, Anyone please help me to find what goes wrong here, thank you in advance

Comment: how did your problem got resolve, i too getting same error and i have used CVPixelBufferCreateWithPlanarBytes(), should i go with the CVPixelBufferCreate()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating cvpixelbufferref by CVPixelBufferCreateWithPlanarBytes(), i have tried creating it by CVPixelBufferCreate(), then i copied the copy manually like this ,

```
baseaddrY=CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(pixelBuffer,0);
baseaddrUV=CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(pixelBuffer,1);

memcpy(baseaddrY,dataY,sizeofY);
memcpy(baseaddrUV,dataUV,sizeofUV);
```

this creates the cvpixelbufferref. this is referred from Anton's answer for the question, [CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage returns error 6683](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12646273/cvopenglestexturecachecreatetexturefromimage-returns-error-6683)

Comment: how did your problem got resolve, i too getting same error and i have used CVPixelBufferCreateWithPlanarBytes(), should i go with the CVPixelBufferCreate()

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation the reason for this error is:

"The pixel buffer is not compatible with OpenGL due to an unsupported buffer size, pixel format, or attribute."

So it means 1 of 2 things:

1: When you are setting up your texture buffer you are using a pixel format not supported in OpenGLES, when calling :

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, w, h, 0, GL_BGRA_EXT, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
```

2 :If i remember rightly its because the video frame image format isn't compatible with the OpenGLES implementation. If its from the device camera i believe its YCbCr and has to be converted to an image which is RGB / RGBA.

Remember that there are different bits per pixel for various image formats too. So check which are supported by iOS i think most are from the Khronos spec, i use mainly RGBA_8888 for quality ). Though the above example works with any PNG i tend to use when not using PVRTC

This shows how to take a frame and using CGImage convert it to an OpenGLES friendly format on iOS that you can use as a texture.

[Convert an UIImage in a texture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14362868/convert-an-uiimage-in-a-texture)

Comment: i am using kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange, and creating textures as the apple's example http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLCameraRipple/Introduction/Intro.html