# Why can I get the GL_LUMINANCE but not the GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA from my camera roll's video?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, avfoundation

In iOS, I would like to play a video from the camera roll, and for a lot of reasons I need to do some OpenGL stuff on each frame.

**My code works when the video comes from the camera, but not from a video from the camera roll**

Here is the code, trying to keep the bare minimum.

Setting up `AVAssetReaderTrackOutput` and `_textureCache` after user selects a video from the camera roll:

```
// Creating _textureCache
CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, NULL, _glContext, NULL, &_textureCache);

// Reading the video track
NSDictionary *settings = @{(id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey: @(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)};
NSArray *videoTracks = [asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
_assetReaderTrackOutput = [[AVAssetReaderTrackOutput alloc] initWithTrack:videoTracks.firstObject outputSettings:settings];
NSError *assetReaderCreationError;
_assetReader = [[AVAssetReader alloc] initWithAsset:asset error:&assetReaderCreationError];
[_assetReader addOutput:_assetReaderTrackOutput];
[_assetReader startReading];
```

For each frame (timer based)

```
if (_assetReader.status == AVAssetReaderStatusReading) {
  sampleBuffer = [_assetReaderTrackOutput copyNextSampleBuffer];
  CVImageBufferRef cameraFrame = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);

  // This works
  CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault, _textureCache, cameraFrame, NULL, GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_LUMINANCE, bufferWidth, bufferHeight, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, &luminanceTextureRef);

  // This doesn't work (err 6833)
  CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault, _textureCache, cameraFrame, NULL, GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA, bufferWidth, bufferHeight, GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 1, &luminanceTextureRef);
```

The last line here ^  doesn't work. I get error 6833. I found this [CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage returns error 6683](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12646273/cvopenglestexturecachecreatetexturefromimage-returns-error-6683) but cannot get more.

I have tried different settings (replacing `kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA` with other enums) but it doesn't get me anywhere. Any help ?

EDIT:

```
frame <CVPixelBuffer 0x1565796b0 width=720 height=1280 bytesPerRow=2880 pixelFormat=BGRA iosurface=0x158300048 attributes=<CFBasicHash 0x156578a40 [0x1a115e150]>{type = immutable dict, count = 1,
entries =>
  0 : <CFString 0x19ca7fca8 [0x1a115e150]>{contents = "PixelFormatDescription"} = <CFBasicHash 0x156551460 [0x1a115e150]>{type = immutable dict, count = 15,
entries =>
  1 : <CFString 0x19ca7fae8 [0x1a115e150]>{contents = "CGImageCompatibility"} = <CFBoolean 0x1a115e6c8 [0x1a115e150]>{value = true}
  2 : <CFString 0x19ca801a8 [0x1a115e150]>{contents = "FillExtendedPixelsCallback"} = <CFData 0x156569340 [0x1a115e150]>{length = 24, capacity = 24, bytes = 0x0000000000000000484e1f85010000000000000000000000}
  5 : <CFString 0x19ca7fee8 [0x1a115e150]>{contents = "ContainsAlpha"} = <CFBoolean 0x1a115e6c8 [0x1a115e150]>{value = true}
  6 : <CFString 0x19ca7fac8 [0x1a115e150]>{contents = "CGBitmapContextCompatibility"} = <CFBoolean 0x1a115e6c8 [0x1a115e150]>{value = true}
  7 : <CFString 0x19ca7ffa8 [0x1a115e150]>{contents = "BitsPerBlock"} = <CFNumber 0xb000000000000202 [0x1a115e150]>{value = +32, type = kCFNumberSInt32Type}
  8 : <CFString 0x19ca7ffc8 [0x1a115e150]>{contents = "BlackBlock"} = <CFData 0x156568660 [0x1a115e150]>{length = 4, capacity = 4, bytes = 0x000000ff}
  9 : <CFString 0x19ca7fbc8 [0x1a115e150]>{contents = "IOSurfaceOpenGLESTextureCompatibility"} = <CFBoolean 0x1a115e6c8 [0x1a115e150]>{value = true}
  10 : <CFString 0x19ca7fc08 [0x1a115e150]>{contents = "OpenGLESCompatibility"} = <CFBoolean 0x1a115e6c8 [0x1a115e150]>{value = true}
  11 : <CFString 0x19ca80088 [0x1a115e150]>{contents = "CGBitmapInfo"} = <CFNumber 0xb000000000020042 [0x1a115e150]>{value = +8196, type = kCFNumberSInt32Type}
  12 : <CFString 0x19ca7fba8 [0x1a115e150]>{contents = "IOSurfaceCoreAnimationCompatibility"} = <CFBoolean 0x1a115e6c8 [0x1a115e150]>{value = true}
  13 : <CFString 0x19ca7fbe8 [0x1a115e150]>{contents = "IOSurfaceOpenGLESFBOCompatibility"} = <CFBoolean 0x1a115e6c8 [0x1a115e150]>{value = true}
  14 : <CFString 0x19ca800a8 [0x1a115e150]>{contents = "ContainsYCbCr"} = <CFBoolean 0x1a115e6d8 [0x1a115e150]>{value = false}
  15 : <CFString 0x19ca7fe88 [0x1a115e150]>{contents = "PixelFormat"} = <CFNumber 0xb000000424752412 [0x1a115e150]>{value = +1111970369, type = kCFNumberSInt32Type}
  16 : <CFString 0x19ca80108 [0x1a115e150]>{contents = "ComponentRange"} = <CFString 0x19ca80148 [0x1a115e150]>{contents = "FullRange"}
  21 : <CFString 0x19ca800c8 [0x1a115e150]>{contents = "ContainsRGB"} = <CFBoolean 0x1a115e6c8 [0x1a115e150]>{value = true}
}

}
 propagatedAttachments=<CFBasicHash 0x156579910 [0x1a115e150]>{type = mutable dict, count = 5,
entries =>
  0 : <CFString 0x19ca7f688 [0x1a115e150]>{contents = "CVImageBufferYCbCrMatrix"} = <CFString 0x19ca7f6c8 [0x1a115e150]>{contents = "ITU_R_601_4"}
  1 : <CFString 0x19ca7f7e8 [0x1a115e150]>{contents = "CVImageBufferTransferFunction"} = <CFString 0x19ca7f6a8 [0x1a115e150]>{contents = "ITU_R_709_2"}
  2 : <CFString 0x19cab2690 [0x1a115e150]>{contents = "MetadataDictionary"} = <CFBasicHash 0x15654c060 [0x1a115e150]>{type = mutable dict, count = 3,
entries =>
  0 : <CFString 0x19cab9970 [0x1a115e150]>{contents = "SNR"} = <CFNumber 0x156515ad0 [0x1a115e150]>{value = +20.18363643733977141892, type = kCFNumberFloat64Type}
  1 : <CFString 0x19cab7cb0 [0x1a115e150]>{contents = "ExposureTime"} = <CFNumber 0x1565623b0 [0x1a115e150]>{value = +0.01000000000000000021, type = kCFNumberFloat64Type}
  2 : <CFString 0x19cab9950 [0x1a115e150]>{contents = "SensorID"} = <CFNumber 0xb000000000002372 [0x1a115e150]>{value = +567, type = kCFNumberSInt32Type}
}

  5 : <CFString 0x19ca7f768 [0x1a115e150]>{contents = "CVImageBufferColorPrimaries"} = <CFString 0x19ca7f6a8 [0x1a115e150]>{contents = "ITU_R_709_2"}
  6 : <CFString 0x19ca7f828 [0x1a115e150]>{contents = "CVImageBufferChromaLocationTopField"} = <CFString 0x19ca7f888 [0x1a115e150]>{contents = "Center"}
}
 nonPropagatedAttachments=<CFBasicHash 0x1565798d0 [0x1a115e150]>{type = mutable dict, count = 0,
entries =>
}
>
Failed to create IOSurface image (texture)
```

Comment: can you `NSLog(@"frame: %@", cameraFrame);` for both camera and file frames and add the output to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using either `kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange` or `kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange` for your `AVAssetReaderTrackOutput` outputOptions.

I would also try this on a device. The simulator did not used to support these formats, although that may have changed.

Comment: kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange works fine!